# Two javascript functions won't work at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, simultaneous

I have one script that shows a tooltip on click and the other script shows a menu after a certain point in the page.

If the menu doesn't load, then I can click on the buttons to show the tooltips just fine. But when the menu does show up, the tooltips script doesn't show anymore.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#left-tooltip').click(function() {
            $('#lollefttooltip').toggle();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#right-tooltip').click(function() {
            $('.right-tooltip').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 650) {
                $("#nav-block:hidden").css('visibility', 'visible');
                $("#nav-block:hidden").fadeIn('650');
                $("#nav-wrap:hidden").css('visibility', 'visible');
                $("#nav-wrap:hidden").fadeIn('650');
                $("#header-wrap:hidden").css('visibility', 'visible');
                $("#header-wrap:hidden").fadeIn('650');
            } else {
                $("#nav-block:visible").fadeOut("650");
                $("#nav-wrap:visible").fadeOut("650");
                $("#header-wrap:visible").fadeOut("650");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

update: Here is all the code I have for this. http://jsfiddle.net/parachutepenny/82J6G/11/

I'm sorry in advance for any beginner errors that I may have all over the place. I'm still learning how to code.

Comment: would be helpful if you posted a jsfiddle demonstrating this issue

Comment: Please provide at least enough HTML/CSS so we can recreate the issue. Otherwise, we can only guess at the problem.

Comment: I think your problem might be the usage of toggle(), is there any chance that your #lollefttooltip has a class of .right-tooltip?

Comment: Why is there 2  $(document).ready function? 
and why is there 2 sets of script tags?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question, but there are some great opportunities to optimize here. Aside from best practice, they may also sort out the bugginess. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // combine doc.ready

    var win  = window, // store window as a variable
        $bod = $('body');

    $('#left-tooltip').click(function() {

        $('#lollefttooltip').toggle();
    });
    $('#right-tooltip').click(function() {

        $('.right-tooltip').toggle();
    });

    $(win).scroll(function() {

        if (win.scrollY > 650) { // use scrollY from window variable so you're not retrieving from the DOM

            $bod.addClass('navVisible'); // use classes on body to trigger CSS transitions on the children
        } else {

            $bod.removeClass('navHidden');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your multiple click function into single ready function.It may cause readability problem.
Follow this link.

[Multiple document.ready() function](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready/)